# Grails - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Proxy could not be initialized

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a domain class called InventoryLineItem that has a property of type InventoryAccess:

```
class InventoryLineItem {

    InventoryAccess inventoryAccess
    ...
}
```

There's another domain class called LineItem that has a property of type InventoryLineItem:

```
class LineItem {

    InventoryLineItem inventoryLineItem
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when I try to access any of the properties of InventoryAccess from the LineItem class (e.g. `inventoryLineItem.inventoryAccess?.allotment`), I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Proxy for [com.acme.inventory.domain.InventoryAccess:8604205056156879654] could not be initialized`

I'm getting the instance to the LineItem instances like so:

```
List<LineItem> lineItemsPendingTransfer = originalDeliveredItemIds.collect { Long id ->
    InventoryLineItem.get(id)?.lineItem
}
```

I then iterate over each of those line items and for each of them I call a method in LineItem that does this:

```
if (inventoryLineItem.inventoryAccess?.allotment?.scannableEndDate?.before(new Date())) {
    return LineItemTransferState.buildUnavailableState(UnavailableTransferReason.OUTDATED)
}
```

This is where the problem happens. As soon as I try to get the `allotment` property from the inventoryAccess object, the exception is thrown.

I tried setting the inventoryAccess property in InventoryLineItem to `lazy: false` but that didn't help.

Comment: You need to give your question more context. Where in your application are you trying to access this? How are you getting the instance of inventoryLineItem? Is this in a controller? A service? Tag library? Include the code from that section of your application.

Comment: I added some context to the original message. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is InventoryAccess a domain class?

Answer (score 0):

If **InventoryAccess** is supposed to be persisted in the database, then it needs to be a domain class as well.

If not, then you can make it a [transient](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html), but then you'll have to set the value yourself. For instance, you can add a *getter* to lazy-initialize the property:

```
class InventoryLineItem {
    InventoryAccess inventoryAccess

    static transients = ['inventoryAccess']

    InventoryAccess getInventoryAccess() {
        if(inventoryAccess == null) {
            // do something to initialize inventoryAcces
        }

        return inventoryAccess
    }
}
```

Comment: InventoryAccess is a domain class. I ended up changing some code around and all is good but I still don't fully understand why things weren't working the way I had it originally coded.